# Windows won't boot after trying to boot linux live usb

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, liveusb

I've created a Linux Tails liveUSB with YUMI, and tried to boot it. I got to the main screen where you get to choose which distro you'd like to boot (since YUMI makes multiboot usb) but I chose the "Continue to boot from First HD" option, which took me to a black screen that said Booting... This screen was on for 15-20 minute without anything changing, so I restarted my computer, but ever since than, I can't boot windows.
I have  a recovery usb, but it also does nothing, once I get to the page that says press enter to try again or press f8 to enter Startup Recovery nothing happens. However, if I plug in the live usb with linux distribution on it, linux loads fine

My HDD is fine, I can access all my data from the linux I boot